# Retweet with comment with Twitter4j

Tags: java, twitter

How can I retweet with comment using Twitter4j client? There is retweet status but it only takes tweetID without the comment content String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A commented status is simply a normal Tweet which ends with a link to another tweet.

For example, if you post this status:

`Wow! This is cool! https://twitter.com/edent/status/554772317738659840`

It will appear as a commented / quoted Tweet.

All you need to know is the Tweet ID and the username in order to create that URL.